# How to deselect row when clicked outside the table? [used: Material-UI DataGrid]

Tags: material-ui

I'm using Material-UI tables for showing my data, and I'm stuck when it comes to deselecting selected row.

So when user clicks outside the table, row should be deselected.

This is my code

```
const showData2 = (e,data) => {
        console.log('selection',e)
    }

<div style={{ height: 180, width: "100%", backgroundColor:'white' }}>
                        <DataGrid
                            rows={cases}
                            density='compact'
                            columns={columnsCases}
                            pageSize={3}
                            hideFooterSelectedRowCount={true}
                            rowHeight={40}
                            onRowSelected = {(e)=>{showData(e)}}
                            onSelectionChange= {(e)=>{showData2(e)}}
                        />
                    </div>
```

Selection works perfectly but it seems impossible to deselect row when clicked outside the table

I would appreciate any idea and help.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ClickAwayListener` to detect if a click event happened outside of an element. It listens for clicks that occur somewhere in the document.

https://material-ui.com/components/click-away-listener/

Answer (score 1):

**Deselect Row Example using the ClickAwayListener with Typescript**

1. Import GridRowId type in addition to whatever other types or components you need from data-grid

   `import { DataGrid, GridColDef, GridRowId } from '@material-ui/data-grid';`
2. Set local state for the selectionModel prop on the DataGrid and init as an empty array.

   `const [selectionModel, setSelectionModel] = useState<GridRowId[]>([]);`
3. Add DataGrid component as child of ClickAwayListener... plus your other DataGrid props.

   ```
    <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => setSelectionModel([])}>
              <DataGrid
                {...otherProps}
                checkboxSelection // <= works with or without checkbox selection
                selectionModel={selectionModel}
                onSelectionModelChange={({ selectionModel }) =>
                  setSelectionModel(selectionModel)
                }
              />
    </ClickAwayListener>
   ```

Of course you can just remove the types if you're not using Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,
Like @Omar EL KHAL said a ClickAwayListener works perfectly.

**Step One:** **Define your onSelectionModelChange and handleClickAway function.**

```
const handleSelection = (newSelection) => {
    if (newSelection)
    {
        setSelectionModel(newSelection.selectionModel);
    }
    else
    {
        setSelectionModel(null);
    }
}
const handleClickAway = () => {
  handleSelection(null);
};
```

**Step Two:** **Define your selectionModel as State**
For this step I chose to set selectionModel in the component state to allow for other functions to set values.

```
const [selectionModel, setSelectionModel] = React.useState([]);
```

**Step Three:** **Set the onSelectionModelChange and selectionModel props**
Set the props props in the Data Grid as follows.

```
<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
    <DataGrid 
    onSelectionModelChange={handleSelection}
    selectionModel={eventSelectionModel}
    />
</ClickAwayListener>
```

Once you save and let NPM do its thing you it should work. 
I personally tested this on a single selection model but it should work with multiple as well. 

P.S. I also did this with functional components and not classed components. The theory would be the same just instead of using useState you would use this.setState.
Happy Coding! 
Gunny

Comment: It is me again.....So after testing some more I figured out that other elements get re-rendered when you click off the table. For me it was a button group, when I would click the button group it would set a very important piece of state to undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for extra state. You could simply call the setSelectionModel function on the ClickAwayListener like so:

```
<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => apiRef.current.setSelectionModel([])}>
// your Data Grid 
</ClickAwayListener>
```